# primefaces message not working

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am implementing a login form with primefaces but my messages are not displayed, what can be?

I've tried using the id field or passing null in method addMessage ().

my xhtml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
          Wellcome<br/>
        <h:form id="login">
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
            <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
            <p:panel header="Login" style="width: 360px;">
                <h:panelGrid id="loginPanel" columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Email:" for="email" />
                <p:inputText id="email" value="#{loginBean.email}" ></p:inputText>
                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                <p:message for="email" />

                <h:outputText value="Senha" for="senha" />
                <p:password id="senha" value="#{loginBean.senha}"  feedback="false" minLength="1"></p:password>
                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                <p:message for="senha" />
                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                <p:commandButton action="#{loginBean.loginAction}" value="Login" update="loginForm" ajax="true"></p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

my bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String email;
    private String senha;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{usuarioSessionBean}")
    private UsuarioSessionBean usuarioSessao;

    public String loginAction()
    {
        //Valida preenchimento dos campos de email e senha
        boolean campoBranco = false;
        if((email == null) || (email.trim().length() == 0))
        {
            campoBranco = true;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Email não informado!","Preencha o email e tente novamente!"));
        }

        if((senha == null) || (senha.trim().length() == 0))
        {
            campoBranco = true;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Senha não informada!","Preencha a senha e tente novamente!"));
        }

        if(campoBranco)
            return "login";
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? He returns to the login page but does not show the messages.

Comment: Try to change your method to `public String loginAction(ActionEvent actionEvent)`

Comment: I changed the method as your recommendation and the commandButton of my xhtml (<p:commandButton action="login" value="Login" update="loginForm" ajax="true" actionListener="#{loginBean.loginAction}"/>). But dont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're updating the wrong id.

```
<h:form id="login" >
    <p:commandButton value="Login" update="loginForm"
                     action="#{loginBean.loginAction}"/>
</h:form>
```

In this case, you need to change `loginForm` to `login` or change the `id` of your form to `loginForm`.

Answer (score 3):

If my understanidng is correct you mean to say you want to show the message to the user, try following:

```
    if((senha == null) || (senha.trim().length() == 0))
            {
                campoBranco = true;
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Senha não informada!","Preencha a senha e tente novamente!"));
    return null;


}
```

this is what you have to add `return null;` so that it will stay in the same page and show up the message, As you are trying to navigate to the login page once agin after getting the error also, it will simply navigate rather than showing error messages.
 as well try to modify in the xhtml as suggested below:

and in your xhtml:

```
<p:growl id="growlLoginValidationStatus" showDetail="true" sticky="false" autoUpdate="true" life="4000" redisplay="false" showSummary="true" globalOnly="false" />
```

and remove your `<p:message/>` tag and make ajax as false in your command button.
try this, if still not able to show the message, let me know in comment

Comment: Not this time. I removed <p:message> tags, changed the my as bean and my xthml as you say, but dont work.

Comment: did you add the return null; statement from the action ?

Comment: Was to return null, I switched to see if it worked. But in my project is return null

Comment: but from your action I can see, you are returning to the mapping "login", instead that return null in case you trying to show the error message, as it will stay in the same page rather than navigating to the mapping, in case as you are doing currently it will navigate to the mapping defined and it will lost the message

Comment: I changed my commandButton to set ajax="false" and works. Do you know why?

Comment: ajax is set to true (default) the commandButton will do an ajax submit instead of an ordinary form submit (full page refresh)...in case you want to show the message while ajax mode set to true, you need to set like this:<h:inputText id="userName" value="#{loginBean.userName}" 
     immediate="true" required="true" requiredMessage="#{messageResource['username.required']}" 
     >
    
    <p:ajax update="growlLoginValidationStatus"/>
    
    </h:inputText> here I mean the 'growlLoginValidationStatus' the ID of your <p:rowl/> id

Comment: Thanks, just one more question.. I want to show messages only in the fields or just on the page, for example: If the user does not fill the e-mail field, the message should be displayed only on <p:message/> field. If the user enters incorrect credentials, display the message only in <p:messages /> (page message). Is it possible?

Comment: you can keep, no issues at all with that, as you are keeping <p:growl/>, this will take care of messages properly just update this and clear the previous error, so that you will get the proper message instead of mixed message...else remove <p:growl/> and keep <p:messages/> and <p:message/> this will work well and good but user will not get notified like popups

Comment: Yes that possible, as gave you example <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{loginBean.userName}" immediate="true" required="true" requiredMessage="#{messageResource['username.required']}" > <p:ajax update="growlLoginValidationStatus"/> </h:inputText>, here update your particular message id, and it will work absolutely fine, provided you are making ajax call for each field as you said field like e-mail id and etc you have to make individual call..in your managed bean setter method of that field you have to set the message .